# What devices should toddlers be allowed to use?

Tags: toddler, tablet-computer

There has been some work on the use of technology by toddlers (for example, [this paper](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/95402302/revisiting-early-use-technology-critical-shift-from-how-young-too-young-to-how-much-just-right)). By and large, there are some advantages to the use of some of these technologies by children. For example, even two-year-old children started collaborating more and working in concert even when they were using their personal iPads (see link above). But there are other disadvantages that might arise through technology use such as access to violence ([source](http://www.children-and-technology.ed.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/children_0-8_and_digital_technology_UK_report_2015.pdf)).

What kind of devices do/did you allow your toddlers to use? If a toddler wants to use an iPad that the parents own, how were they allowed to use the iPad? Are there any apps that would be interesting/useful for them when using such technology?

Comment: This is an open ended survey question based on opinion, and also seeks product recommendations. It meets most of the off topic criteria.

Comment: @CreationEdge > I think it could be edited to fit the standards. The question in itself is quite interesting. For example the current advises we received were "no screen up to 3, no videogames up to 6". We personally found this anachronic so our baby girl is using the ipad and watching TV on occasions, but from the really quick addiction she develops to it we now limit it very much. I think it would be interesting to see articles similar to the ones linked in the question or even get professional answers.

Comment: @LaurentS I don't VTC based on whan the question *could* be, though. This should be closed until an on topic question is made from it.

Comment: As CreationEdge mentioned, this is open-ended and broad. It has a very good _basis_ however, so I encourage editing so it is a better fit and I think it will easily be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tradition we have with the ipad and other screen devise is [not to allow the toddler to be alone on the machine](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jordanshapiro/2013/12/04/research-says-parents-and-kids-should-play-video-games-together/), and only for a few minutes at a time (20-40 min). When the time is up we brake into other activity like eating or what ever we had planed so there is no Drama or tantrums that the toy is taken away from the child. We do this so that the child has an idea about how to use the technology without taking to much time from other things.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful answer. I think it makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not so much about what devices/apps should be allowed but about the time limits.

Our daughter, now 3.5 is allowed to use the iPhone or the Laptop, but we try to limit it to max. half an hour.

From experience she rarely stops using electronic devices herself, we have to enforce the limit.

She likes browsing photos, Videos on YouTube, Skype (with her grandparents or cousin)  and Tamagotchi like animal apps.

She has friends who are using devices a lot more than her, but i think at this age it is enough to know the basic idea how they work.